# Inheritance and overloading of the function call operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have a problem in trying to inherit a function call operator from a parent structure. I created a simple code to ilustrate my question:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
struct array
{
    T value[N];
    T& operator() (int);
};

template <class T, int N>
T& array<T,N>::operator() (int i)
{ return value[i]; }

template <class T, int N>
struct matrix: public array<T,N*N>
{
    T& operator() (int,int);
};

template <class T, int N>
T& matrix<T,N>::operator() (int i, int j)
{ return this->value[i*N+j]; }

int main()
{
    matrix<double,100> a;
    a(0) = 3.5;
    cout << a(0) << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

I expected the 'matrix' class to inherit the operator() from the 'array' class, and overload it with the local operator(); I would expect this because the number of arguments is different. However, the compilation of this code fails with messages like "error: no match for call to ‘(matrix) (int)’" and "note: candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided". If the operator() is not defined in the class 'matrix', then the inheritance occurs normally and the code compiles and runs fine, as expected.

What am I doing wrong? I would like not to have to redefine operator() unnecessarily...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way name lookup works in C++, the moment the compiler finds a name, it stops looking. In other words, the compiler first finds the `operator()` in `matrix` and stops looking, never finding the one in `array`.

You can explicitly bring the base `operator()` into scope with a using declaration:

```
template <...>
struct matrix : public array<...> {
  using array::operator();
  T& operator ()(int, int);
}
```

Comment: you beat me to it. Here is a good explaination on the topic http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/hiding-rule.html

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that (although that's the explication here).  Additional names can be brought in via ADL, for example; the compiler doesn't just stop as soon as it finds a name.

Comment: True, but doesn't apply to class member lookup.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian! I didn't know I could do that. And thanks to PorkyBrain for the reference.
Just for the purpose of rigorous correctness, the relevant line must contain the template parameters:
    using array<...>::operator();

Comment: Try `using matrix::array::operator()` instead. Saves you from repeating the template parameters. Though both are completely valid.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a member function with a given name, it will mask all inherited functions which have the same name. This means it won't overload them by default, even if there are a different number of parameters, or they are of a different type etc.

However, you can bring the base class functions into the child class's scope with a `using` declaration. In your case, put this somewhere in your `matrix` class:

```
using array<T, N*N>::operator ();
```

Answer (score 1):

By overloading the base class function in derive class you have made the base class function hidden. To access the base class function either you have to redefine the base class function "T& operator() (int)" in derive class or you can use "using array::operator();".